# Resolving GLIBCXX symbols in Alpine build

Tags: c++, gcc, alpine-linux

I'm working on porting the C++ build pipeline from Ubuntu image to Alpine.

Currently, my application is compiled in the following ENV:

- Ubuntu AMD64 container with installed cross-compiler
- 3rd-party dynamic library (I cannot modify it)

Target platform is an Alpine ARM container.

---

**Notice:** the application is running in Alpine ARM container WITHOUT GCOMPAT PACKAGE.

So, I can state, that the 3rd-party library does not require original glibc and can live with musl.

---

I've carefully re-created the original ENV in Alpine image. But looks like something is missing because during application linkage, I see symbols mismatch:

`/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: lib3rd-party.so: undefined reference to 'std::exception::what() const@GLIBCXX_3.4'`

---

**My question is:**

Since the 3rd-party library does not require any compatibility layer with glibc (e.g. gcompat), it looks like it only needs a specific version of glibc++. How can I solve this properly on Alpine?

*(Maybe I can somehow ignore version symbols or mock them, or at least put required libstdc++ library manually)*

P.S.: Please correct me if I'm wrong with my assumptions!

Comment: I think this would be tricky because Alpine musl linker doesn't have full support for symbol versioning: https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html#Symbol-versioning
It will fall back to the default `std::exception::what() const` version available. I'm not sure if it's the oldest or newest, though. So even if you have the GNU libstdc++ installed it needs to be such that it will fall back to that symbol when linking.
Just to make sure, do you have `libstdc++6` package installed? And which Alpine version?

Comment: Hi @valiano, Alpine is 3.13.5, the `libstdc++6` package is not installed.